# How to rewrite URL and get the values?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, shortcode, url-rewriting, urls

I created a shortcode by [`add_shortcode`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode). where the shortcode placed in a wordpress page to display dynamic content. The dynamic content is based on the URL value.

**Example**

If URL is `wordpress/sample-page/?user=john` in my shortcode content I get the url value by `$_GET['user']`

Now I would like to rewrite the url like `wordpress/sample-page/john`. And want to get the URL values in shortcode. Is this possible in wordpress? if so Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and quickest solution would be to use the [`add_rewrite_endpoint`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) function.

```
<?php add_rewrite_endpoint( $name, $places ); ?>
```

So in your case it would be something like this:

```
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'user', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );
```

An user URL would look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/my-page/user/john
```

To access the variable:

```
$user = get_query_var( 'user', false );
```